# How to avoid AWS S3 changing file content-type from text/html?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 to host a static website for a portfolio. For each webpage the `.html`extension is removed. The problem with this is that AWS automatically categorizes the file as `binary/octet-stream`. The problem here is that when you access the extension such as `myportfolio.com/contact` instead of rendering the page, the file just downloads into the downloads folder.

By going to

> [Object] → properties → metadata → content-type

I am able to change the type to `text/html` which causes the file to render instead of downloading.

Now after having made a change to all the files and re-uploading them using `AWS Cli`:

`AWS s3 sync . s3://[bucketname]`

the files went back to the old content-type. How do I permanently set the content type on these files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the --content-type flag? For example,

> AWS s3 sync . s3://[bucketname] --content-type "text/html"

More info on this can be found here in the [sync documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

**UPDATE:** try this command for deployment,

> aws s3 sync --acl public-read --sse --delete . s3://[bucketname]

--acl sets the files to be public read, --sse stores files encrypted, --delete removes files that are not in your local file.

Comment: I haven't but this helps. So with `sync .`  it uploads all updated files. Obviously if something like an image file was in the upload, using that flag wouldn't be helpful. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @JohnSnow hmm, I did not think of that. I wonder if instead doing:
> aws s3 sync --acl public-read /path s3://[bucketname]

Comment: @JohnSnow did you use the commands when you created your s3 bucket from cli? I wonder if your bucket is set to static website mode? ALSO I updated my answer above with a better command to deploy everything. Content type should automatically be detected.

> aws s3 mb s3://yourportfolio.com
> aws website s3://yourportfolio.com --index-document index.html --error-document error.html

My quick example here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/nomnomtech.com/index.html

Comment: @JohnSnow I hope I was able to help you sir. :)